# how to Implement/show google Map in Window mobile 6.x?

Tags: windows, windows-mobile

I am current developing application window mobile 6. Is there any control or any other way through which i can implement google map in my application. I know that using bing map control we can show map in window phone 7 application. but i need to show map on window mobile 6 application. so how it can be possible ?

Thanks in advance .....

Comment: I guess you could try using the webbrowser control.